# How to permanently append X to complete a shorthand URL via htaccess rewrite for a bi lingual site?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Using htaccess how can one achieve the following on a bilingual (the only two languages being: `en|nl`)?

if typed `website.org/en` (without anything after `/en`) then permanently redirect to `website.org/en/home`

if typed `website.org/nl` (without anything after `/nl`) then permanently redirect to `website.org/nl/home`

However, I dont want to just randomly add `/home` after any `/*` So this is only to catch incomplete shorthand urls `/en` and `/nl`, since normally all other urls always have `/en/some page name`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this rule as **your topmost rule**:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(en|nl)/?$ /$1/home [L,NC,R=301]
```